# Maven dependency gives ValidatorException warning for each dependency

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I added [this gradle library](https://github.com/SkriptLang/Skript) to my maven project, and it seems I get the following error for every dependency in the library:

```
Could not transfer metadata groupId:artifactID:version/maven-metadata.xml from/to repoId (http://repolink): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The exception is thrown for a http and https repo link, and isn't thrown for any of my other dependencies, just this one dependency for some reason.

I've looked for the causes of this, and every other error is a certificate error, but I use a different library from the same repo and don't get this error, so it's not a certificate error, but I still get a certification path error? The library still works though, it's just a warning and not causing a big problem.

Comment: Are you behind a http proxy

Comment: Nope, no proxy at all.

Comment: This error happens when the repo is using a certificate which is not on the trust store of the JVM.

Comment: But the repo does have a certificate which is in the trust store of the JVM, hence why other dependencies work from the same repo. It's a cloudflare signed certificate.

Comment: That's strange are you sure you have only one repo configured. check your settings.xml.

Comment: I tested it on two computers, one with a settings.xml with repo1.maven.org and one without a manually configurated settings.xml. It seems all the warnings have a specific repo on it, signed by Lets Encrypt Authority X3, even though that is not where the artifact is from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208097/discussion-between-big-bad-e-and-karthikeyan-vaithilingam).